# Layout Alignment Issue in android 5.0

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-relativelayout

I have a layout in which a button is aligned at the bottom of the RelativeLayout as in below code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:background="@color/background_material_light"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<View
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/strokeColor"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlHeaderFilter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/strokeColor"/>

    <TextView
        android:background="@color/actionbar_background"
        android:id="@+id/tvFilterText"
        style="@style/textStyleHeading2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="Filter Search" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/refresh"
        android:id="@+id/resetLeadsFilter"
        android:contentDescription="@string/emptyString"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="6dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_below="@+id/rlHeaderFilter"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/tvBudgetFromFilter"
    style="@style/textSpinnerStyleHeading"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:hint="Budget From"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvBudgetFromFilter"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/tvBudgetToFilter"
    style="@style/textSpinnerStyleHeading"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:hint="Budget To"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<include
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvBudgetToFilter"
    android:id="@+id/sourceLayout"
    layout="@layout/source_layout" />

<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/statusLayout"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sourceLayout"
    layout="@layout/status_layout" />

<Button
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:background="@color/actionbar_background"
    android:text="SEARCH"
    android:id="@+id/bFilterLeads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I can see the button at the bottom of the layout as shown in the screenshot .It displays like this in pre Lollipop devices(below < 5.0 devices) :

[image]

But in Lollipop the button at the bottom does not appear as shown in following screenshot :

[image]

I am not able to get the reason for that Please help me out . Thanks in advance .

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html  look at 5.0 "toolbar" vs 'actionbar'

Comment: @RobertRowntree Hi Robert I think it is the issue of layout weights. I dont know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Noticed actionbar was being used and wanted to alert u to advice to think about switch to TB

Comment: @Jai I havn't found the solution for it . But i think the issue was in library i used for implementing navigation drawer . I switched to Sliding Menu and it worked for me . But it is not the solution for the problem.

Comment: @lakshay : yeah, it is no the proper solution, even I'm not using any navigation drawer or sliding menu, I'm simply taking 2 childs of relative layout to overlay the second one but it is not working in case of 5.0. Both childs are different components then when I changed it to the same components, it is working fine. so still didn't find core solution :)

Answer (score 2):

I have solved my problem ! In fact, the LinearLayout was behind the navigationBar. To fix it, just add this line to the Activity (after setContentView();)

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

Comment: What is SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION?
I can't find it here.
Having same issue

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the layout behaves differently between Lollipop/pre-Lollipop (unless there's some other piece that's not shown).  I will point out though that I don't think `layoutGravity` is valid for views within a `RelativeLayout` -- that's something you'd use with a `LinearLayout`.  I'd first remove that property and see how it behaves on pre-Lollipop, and then see about correcting the layout once that's done.  It could be that `layoutGravity` is causing some sort of incorrect behavior pre-Lollipop.

Comment: I did that but result is same !!.